# Popup Is Open Based on 2 Conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Custom UserControl that is based on a Popup (Extending a Popup).
Now in this UserControl I have this:

```
     <Popup.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Popup">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OpenPopupStoryBoard" >
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10"  Value="True"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ClosePopupStoryBoard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="False"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Popup.Style>
```

So now I call this in another UserControl, basically the popup gets opened When going over a ListItem with your mouse via

```
<CustomControls:StandardPopup Isopen={Binding Value.Items.Count, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ItemsCountToBoolean}, ConverterParameter=0}, PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=listboxItem}" Heading="ListItemDetails" >
```

Now my problem is, I am trying to not Show the popup when there is no Items, but because there is a trigger already of IsOpen=MouseOver, it does not work based on count of the items. How can I solve this.

I also already tried a CanOpen Dependecy Property on my CustomUserControl an then tried to bind to the IsOpen on my StoryBoard, but Apperently one cannot use Binding in a StoryBoard.

So I guess I am looking for a solution to Set the IsOpen base on a trigger and a binding.

Comment: MultiDataTrigger? Also, if you're binding to a Count property of a collection, make sure it implements INotifyPropertyChanged on the Count property (ObservableCollection does, List does not), otherwise you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Converter in this `DataTrigger`

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">`

An example could be :

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource CheckListBoxCnv}}" Value="True">`

```
public class CheckListBoxConverter:IValueConverter
 {
   //Check for IsMouseOver property there and do some extra processing,  and return true/false value.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you determine whether there are no "items" in the Popup but as Arie suggests you could use a MultiDataTrigger with several conditions. Here is an example for you:

```
<Style TargetType="Popup">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding PlacementTarget.IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
            <!-- add your other condtion here that determines whether there are any items in the Popup, e.g.: -->
            <Condition Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OpenPopupStoryBoard" >
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.10"  Value="True"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ClosePopupStoryBoard">
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiDataTrigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OpenPopupStoryBoard"/>
            <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ClosePopupStoryBoard" />
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Of course you must modify the second condition to bind to some existing property that determines whether there are any items to display but you should get the idea.

Comment: I thank you for the answer, but for some reason the popup doesnt work at all in a listboxItemTemplate, for everything else it works. Any Ideas? So now in my popup control I created a dependency property "CanOpen" and default is set to "True". I have added the code above for Condition MouseOver and CanOpen - <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=popupRoot, Path=CanOpen}" Value="True"/>  My usercontrols name is popupRoot. And in another UserControl I have a Listbox, in the ListboxItemTemplate I set CanOpen=True (Just to test I didnt put in the Count). Just for this listbox it does not work.

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible sample of your issue.